# How to use readFile

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am having trouble reading in a level file in Haskell. The goal is to read in a simple txt file with two numbers seperated by a space and then commas. The problem I keep getting is this: Couldn't match type `` `IO' with `[]' ``

If I understand correctly the do statement is supposed to pull the String out of the Monad.

```
readLevelFile :: FilePath -> [FallingRegion]
readLevelFile f = do
        fileContent <-  readFile f
        (map lineToFallingRegion (lines fileContent))

lineToFallingRegion :: String -> FallingRegion
lineToFallingRegion s = map textShapeToFallingShape (splitOn' (==',') s) 

textShapeToFallingShape :: String -> FallingShape
textShapeToFallingShape s = FallingShape (read $ head numbers) (read $ head 
$ tail numbers)
                      where numbers = splitOn' (==' ') s
```

Comment: "If I understand correctly the do statement is supposed to pull the String out of the Monad." Not quite. Have you done any IO in Haskell before?

Comment: No, this is my first time dealing with IO and Monads. I have been working from the examples at http://learnyouahaskell.com. And I have read through the book.

Comment: Very roughly, `do x <- action ; ...` does pull `x` out of the IO `action`, but _only_ if the subsequent `...` are still working inside IO, so that the final return type is of the form `IO something`. There is no way to just "remove IO" -- this is because, by design, we want `IO` to show up in the return type of any function which does IO. That's the whole point! You could read [monads in picutres](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pull things out of `IO`. You can think of `IO` as a container (in fact, some interpretations of `IO` liken it to the box containing Schrödinger's cat). You can't see what's in the container, but if you *step into* the container, values become visible.

So this should work:

```
readLevelFile f = do
    fileContent <-  readFile f
    return (map lineToFallingRegion (lines fileContent))
```

It does not, however, have the type given in the OP. Inside the `do` block, `fileContent` is a `String` value, but the entire block is still inside the `IO` container.

This means that the return type of the function isn't `[FallingRegion]`, but `IO [FallingRegion]`. So if you change the type annotation for `readLevelFile` to

```
readLevelFile :: FilePath -> IO [FallingRegion]
```

you should be able to get past the first hurdle.

Comment: I don't think `do { fileContent <- readFile f; map ... }` should work; it needs a `return` around the `map` or some similar change.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, you're correct. Thank you for the correction. I admit that I didn't try to compile the code, because the code in the OP is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your first function with explicit types:

```
readLevelFile f = do
    (fileContent :: String) <-
                  (readFile :: String -> IO String) (f :: String) :: IO String
```

`fileContent` is indeed of type `String` but is only available within the execution of the IO Monad under which we are evaluating.  Now what?

```
    (map lineToFallingRegion (lines fileContent))  :: [String]
```

Now you are suddenly using an expression that is not an `IO` monad but instead is a list value - since lists are also a type of monad the type check tries to unify `IO` with `[]`.  What you actually wanted is to return this value:

```
return (map lineToFallingRegion (lines fileContent)) :: IO [String]
```

Now recalling that we can't ever "exit" the IO monad your `readLevelFile` type must be IO - an honest admission that it interacts with the outside world:

```
readLevelFile :: FilePath -> IO [FallingRegion]
```